# gridview odd numbered row indexes does not show data

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Gridview have a category column.
This column Edit template has a DropDownList.
The dropdownlist datasource:

```
protected void grdProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ds = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCategory");
        int ids = Convert.ToInt16(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("LID")).Text);
        ds.DataTextField = "Name";
        ds.DataValueField = "ID";
        ds.DataSource = model.Categories.ToList();
        ds.DataBind();
        var idBynames = model.Products.Where(s => s.ID == ids).FirstOrDefault();
        string names = idBynames.CategoryName;
        var categorys = model.Categories.Where(s => s.Name == names).FirstOrDefault();
        ds.SelectedValue = categorys.ID.ToString();
    }
}
```

So problem is odd numbered row indexes the dropdownlist empty but even numbered row indexes works fine. what is problem? i can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that [`DataControlRowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx) has the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) set on it.  If you have an AlternatingRowStyle set, then your alternating rows will have `RowState` including the flag `DataControlRowState.Alternate`.

Try checking for the `DataControlRowState.Edit` flag regardless of any other flags, by changing your `if` statement to:

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

Adding the bitwise operator checks just the flag value for `Edit`.